# Mongo and mongod command shows error in macos

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I run mongod the following error shows:

Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

Comment: could you please share mongo logs